# Search Optimization through Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, seo

We are trying to set up a repository for a large number of documents in our organization.

What client needs is - to make the search as good as possible, by using SharePoint 2013 and its functionalities.

We are implementing various features like tagging, taxonomy, etc. and also analytics for all the documents, to get an idea about how system is performing.

Can you advise on what we can do to make the search for documents at its best for the end users?

Comment: Please add details about what you are trying to achive? Your question is not very clear right now

Comment: We are trying to set up a repository for a large number of documents in our organization. What client needs is - to make the search as good as possible, by using sharepoint 2013 and its functionalities. We are implementing various features like tagging, taxonomy, etc. and also analytics for all the documents, to get an idea about how system is performing. Can you advise on what we can do to make the search for documents at its best for the end users?

Comment: Tapan, I have to agree with Robert. Making search optimal you need to have a target or goal. The question should be more specific such as do you intend to search only PDFs? Do you intend to exclude lists that should not appear in the search? Do you need to scope the search to selected site collections? subsites? You cannot simply throw in saying you are using taxonomy, tagging, etc. All of these are given features in SharePoint.

Comment: Hi Joe. Thanks for guidance. I will be more specific as to what we are upto. There are numerous documents which are accessed by employees in the organization through shared drives as of now. These documents serve various service lines and according folders have been named in those shared drives. What we are trying to achieve is - to set up an Enterprise Content Management system by implementing SharePoint 2013 as the platform, which will have just one site, and under that site these various documents will sit as per service lines. So, we need a system to make the search as good as possible.

Comment: So, instead of using shared drives, we want people to go and just type the required document name as per service line or content it has, and get the exact document he or she wants. Does that make sense?

Comment: One more point -  the search is not just for PDFs. The folders in all shared drives contain documents which are in word file, ppt, pdfs, excel files, tableau generated reports etc. Basically, all these type of documents contain data which contains lots of information related to specific service lines or domains. Please let me know Joe and Robert, if you want me to provide more specific information. Really appreciate your help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much beyond the scope of Stack Exchange to deal with. Enterprise Content Management is a huge and complex field. There are a great many consultancy companies out there whose entire business model revolves around  building Document Management Systems in SharePoint. They never do anything else.

The system you describe can be built in sharepoint. I have worked on similar systems before for several enterprise scale clients and I am currently building something similar for a major university in the UK. To properly plan and implement such a system usually takes 3-6 months depending on the size of the organisation and the ammount of data to migrated into the new CMS.

I gave some general guidance to a similar question a few months back which I'll link to here:
[Build a IT document system](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115865/build-a-it-document-system/115947#115947)

The best advice I can give is to find out what sort of budget you ahve for this project and tender for a SharePoint consultancy with plenty of experience of ECMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot JonT for sharing knowledge on the issue. Appreciate that.